# Example on using ldap authentication for apache http client to make rest api calls

Tags: java

Can any one give example on how to configure apache http client to use ldap authentication instead of Basic authentication.
For basic authentication,following is the code.

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(get_taskStatus_url);

String authData = userName + ":" + userName;
String encoded = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(authData
                .getBytes());
get.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
get.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
get.setHeader("ACCEPT", "application/xml");

HttpResponse cgResponse = client.execute(get);
```

What changes do I need to perform in order to make ldap authentication instead of basic authentication.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by ldap authentication? HTTP defines several authentication schemes and I do not see how ldap is one of them.

Comment: I mean, My http client request should look up ldap server for validating user name and password.How to tell Http Client that look up in the ldap server for authentication. Kindly provide sample code

Comment: Do you mean you want to validate the credential before sending them to the server? What do you send to the server then, and what does it do with it?

Comment: I am making rest api calls to jbpm server.It uses basic authentication.Please look at the code i have mentioned in top of the page,                                    it has "Basic" in it.   get.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);.How to tell it ,do this authentication against Ldap server.

Comment: You can do nothing for that with the client code, you need to configure your server to validate the credential on ldap. As jbpm is using Jboss you must configure it like explained here : https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/drools-guvnor-docs/html/ch16.html

Comment: Thank you very much for advice.So can i do just 'Basic' validation, and do changes mentioned in the document.Sorry to bother you with my basic questions.

Comment: Yes but you must do those changes on jbpm.

Comment: Ok Sir, I will do necessary changes mentioned in document in jbpm side.